# Каким образом контроль целостности данных связана с валидацией и верификацией?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, валидация

Подскажите пожалуйста:

1. Контроль целостности включает в себя валидацию и верификацию данных?
2. Контроль целостности данных СУБД осуществляется в какой момент? В момент записи, обновления данных? Каким образом?

Answer (score 2):

Контроль целостности проверяет связи между таблицами, так что работает при инсерте, апдейте и удалении. В какой-то мере это можно назвать валидацией, т.к не пропустит запрос с неправильным ключем. Но валидацией называют обычно другое.
"Каким образом" - не даст выполнить запрос.

Я это читал более десяти лет назад в англоязычной документации к oracle и/или mysql. [Вот тут например](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) можно почитать как задать связи между таблицами. Думаю это и в переводе есть. После задания внешних ключей/связей контроль целостности не даст выполнить запрос содержащий не верные ключи, так же станет возможно выполнить каскадное удаление, для удаления записи в одной таблице и в связанных. или наоборот не будет возможности удалить строку в таблице если другие таблицы ссылаются на нее.

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к вопросу;) Подскажите пожалуйста, а есть какой то источник где описаны эти определения? Что такое контроль целостности, валидация..

Answer (score 2):

Целостность данных описывается поддержкой СУБД т.н. модели ACID.

Валидацию компания Майкрософт переводит как удостоверение. Т.е. необходимо удостовериться в том, что в базе все связи и объекты описаны верно и операции проводятся соответствующие. Если вы удостоверились, то значит валидация прошла успешно